# Pandas profiling package takes lot of time in generating html report

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-profiling

It takes more than 1 minute to generate HTML report for pandas data profiling. The profiling finishes in just 3s but the report takes most of the time, how can I optimize it.

```
    profile = ProfileReport(df, title="Pandas Profiling Report",minimal=True)
    matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend('Agg')
    text=profile.to_html()
```

[Time requires](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cX4i.png)